# EOFError error trying to use Amazon SES via SMTP with Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, smtp

I have a Rails app configured to use Amazon SES via SMTP. When I try and send email, though, it appears to timeout after a minute, and I get an EOFError. It smells like a configuration issue--the email seems to be constructed fine, and I can send myself test emails from the AWS SES console. This is in sandbox mode, and the app is running in development mode, but both the sending and receiving emails have been verified with SES, and development.rb is set up with this:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I've tried a million config variations; this is starting to drive me bananas. Any help or guidance would be very, very appreciated. More details:

The smtp config, which I have in an initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  :port           => "465",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name      => "1234",
  :password       => "abcde"
 }
```

The logs with the error, a bit truncated for brevity:

```
Sent mail to john@phu.com (59929ms)
Date: Tue, 20 Dec 2011 03:08:37 -0800
From: contact@phu.com
To: john@phu.com
Message-ID: <4ef06cb5ed3c_d73c3fc604c34d4491943@Johns-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Your invitation to Phu
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
....

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60564ms

EOFError (end of file reached):
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:61:in `block in send_invite'
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:46:in `send_invite'
```

Comment: Does your ISP allow outbound connections on port 465? Can you use your amazon smtp credentials with a normal mail client?

Comment: Did you get this to work? Because I have the same issue...

Comment: Haven't gotten it working yet--ended up using Gmail via smpt, which was good enough for the time being. I'll try Mihir's solution below and report back (and accept the answer if it works).

Frederick, I was able to use smtp outside of Rails--it's my own server instance, the ports are open.

Answer (score 10):

There is also a solution without the monkey-patch solution from Mihir (which, according to AWS SES documentation, http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.Connecting.html, is the TLS wrapper solution), by using port 587 and :enable_starttls_auto option (the STARTTLS solution).  So the modified config is such:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: “<example.com>” }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address: “email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com”,
    :port: 587,
    :domain: “<example.com>”,
    :authentication: :login,
    :user_name: “<your aws smtp username>”,
    :password: “<your aws smtp password>”,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html), port 465 is for ssmtp (smtp over SSL).  For SMTP with STARTTLS you need to use port 25 or 587 as you discovered.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution in case you want  to use SMTP (and not the AWS-SES gem)

http://blog.readypulse.com/2012/01/06/amazon-ses-smtp-emails-using-rails-3-1-in-three-easy-steps/

Things to note

AWS SMTP only works on TLS
AWS SMTP does NOT support STARTTLS
ActionMailer’s configuration does not have an easy TLS switch.
Steps to follow

Enable SMTP support on your AWS Console – See instructions here.
Create an initializer under your config/initializers directory. I am calling it amazon_ses.rb and add following code to money patch ActionMailer’s SMTP settings.

```
module Net
    class SMTP
        def tls?
            true
        end
    end
end
```

Add following code in your development.rb and production.rb files. Modify the settings to match your environment.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: “<example.com>” }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: “email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com”,
    port: 465,
    domain: “<example.com>”,
    authentication: :login,
    user_name: “<your aws smtp username>”,
    password: “<your aws smtp password>”
}
```

Comment: I got this working when I put the module changes in the same file as the mail settings.

Comment: (On Rails 3.2) I had to add `require 'net/smtp'` to the top of the initializer file (above `module Net`).  I think it was loading the initializer, and then loading the actual library later, overriding the monkey patch.

Comment: This worked for me with the addition of the following smtp_settings:

  :openssl_verify_mode  => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.5

Comment: In my tests (Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.15) this patch was necessary when using ports 25 and 465, but not for 587.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution for me was this monkey patch

Answer (score 1):

SES requires a SSL session before the EHLO command is sent.

I know System.Net.Mail doesn't work with SES, because System.Net.Mail initiates the TLS after the SMTP session has started.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but if I'm reading [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/732c724df61bc8b780dc42817625b25a321908e4) correctly, ActionMailer (Rails equivalent of System.Net.Mail) does initiate TLS prior to starting the session.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue using Rails 2.3, with Ruby 1.8.7, in dev mode with a sandboxed SES account, sending to/from verified senders.

I worked around it by adding in the [unofficial aws-ses gem](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses). Stick it in your Gemfile, and then replace the smtp settings with these 5 lines:

```
  # Configure mail sending options: Use AWS-SES for all environments
  config.after_initialize do
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :amazon_ses
    ActionMailer::Base.custom_amazon_ses_mailer = AWS::SES::Base.new(:secret_access_key => 'asfd/1234', :access_key_id => 'ABCD')
  end
```

Sending then worked as expected…which tells me the emails themselves were getting set up correctly.

I've done a lot of googling, and haven't seen any confirmation that SES-SMTP is compatible with Rails 2.3 + Ruby 1.8.7. Nor have I found anything that explicitly denies it either, beyond your & my experience.

Let us know if you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on Rails 3.2.12 adding  require 'net/smtp' to  the initializer file with the module change like:

```
require 'net/smtp'

  module Net
    class SMTP
      def tls?
        true
      end
    end
 end
```